# Can't start picamera at Raspbian startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspicam, opencv, lxterminal

I want to run an opencv-python program at Raspbian startup.
The program is to capture images continuously from picamera and do some image processing using opencv and display it in full-screen mode. But it failed to start the program and show some errors in the terminal.

For that I did the following things.

Create a folder named **autostart** in **.config** folder, then copy-paste terminal shortcut to this folder. this is done to start the terminal at startup.
Then added the command

*python filename.py* at the end of **.bashrc** file

[image: Error image]

Here is my code:

```py
import cv2
import time
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import numpy as np

camera = PiCamera()
camera.rotation=90
camera.resolution = (320,240)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size = (320,240))
time.sleep(0.1)

def multi_clahe(img, num):
    for i in xrange(num):
        img = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=
      (4+i*2,4+i*2)).apply(img)
     return img


sharp_kern = np.array((
[-1, -1, -1],
[-1, 9, -1],
[-1, -1, -1]), dtype="int")



while True:   
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", 
use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array 
small = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=1, fy=1) 


gray = cv2.cvtColor(small, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

his_img = multi_clahe(gray,4)

#segments = slic(small, n_segments = 100, sigma = 5)    
#mark_boundaries(img_as_float(his_img), segments)

sharp_img = cv2.filter2D(his_img, -1, sharp_kern)

final = cv2.GaussianBlur(his_img, (5,5),0)
    bod=cv2.copyMakeBorder(final,20,20,20,20,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    vis = np.concatenate((bod, bod), axis=1)
    cv2.namedWindow("final", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)          
    cv2.setWindowProperty("final", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

#cv2.imshow('multi_clahe',his_img)
cv2.imshow('final',vis)
   # cv2.imshow('original',small)
    if cv2.waitKey(50) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
rawCapture.truncate(0)  


 cap.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You really don't want to start anything that uses picamera from .bashrc; that file will be sourced in several places due to auto-login and no more than one process can use the camera at once. I'd follow MatsK's suggestion of using `/etc/rc.local` (but be careful as your script will be running as root)

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer,

When I give a delay of 2 seconds, it worked fine.

And I found another solution to start the program at startup.
created a script file which contain the program to run at startup.

Add this file in `home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`
by typing `@sh /home/pi/scriptfilename.sh`

Actually my script file is placed in /home/pi so that i give the path like this

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

A program that should run at:

- OS is booting `/etc/rc.local`
- User login `/home/USER/.bashrc`

And to troubleshoot, pipe the output from your python program to a file and add that to your question.

Example:

```
python filename.py > logfile.log
```